# Automatic parallelization friendly programming practices

Tags: java, c, serialization, numbers, parallel-processing

From [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.65.2880&rep=rep1&type=pdf): Avoid unnecessarily serializing algorithms: Algorithms such as random
number generators that must pass a seed to the next generator call serialize
the algorithm unnecessarily if the number of times the generator will be
called within a thread cannot be accurately predicted. These algorithms
should be replaced with more distributed versions, instead.

Q: Can anyone please explain **"serialize the algorithm unnecessarily if the number of times the generator will be called within a thread cannot be accurately predicted."** As for random number 
generation we have to pass a seed. Thus how can serialization be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a RNG that depends on its previous value (most) and you write it like this:

```
r = Random.new();
for(int i=0; i<100*usersInput; i++) 
    r.rand();
}
```

It cannot be automatically parallelized even by a smart compiler. However, if you write it like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<usersInput; i++) {
    r = Random.new();
    [for(int j=0; j<100; j++) {
        r.rand();
    }] fork
}
```

A very smart compiler can make the program run in usersInput-number-of-threads, each will only have to run 100 iterations instead of usersInput*100.